# Strange variable/method/class names - PHP

Tags: php

I've a php file that I can't read it because all variables/functions have strange names!
A block of function of my file is:

```
public static function    …………  …… …  ($   ………  …  ……  , $   …… ………  ……  )
{
    $   …… ……   ……   = strpos(   …………… … ……  ::   ……… ……… …   ($   ………  …  ……  ) , $   …… ………  ……  );

    return (false !== $   …… ……   ……  ) ? (int)floor($   …… ……   ……   / 4) : false;
}
```

*As I know php standards don't allow to use dots and spaces in varaible name.*

I myself just came with if there is something related to `character encoding`! as I found, file encoding is `windows-1252`.

Can these **dots** and **spaces** be converted to something readable?

*Also because they are variables/functions, they have more than one occurrence in file.*

***Edited #1***

I open file like always with Notepad++/Sublime Text under Widnows OS and It's not paid or something.

***Edited #2***

Script works without problem!

***Edited #3***

Link to file: `https://www.dropbox.com/s/hoegvk0vz53cnyn/include.php`

Comment: Where did you get this file from? Does the license you got it under actually allow you to modify it? Clearly whoever provided it went to some trouble to obfuscate. You certainly *can* replace the junk with more readable characters, but not with useful variable names unless you understand what the code's doing.

Comment: What happens when you use UTF8? Do the dots stay as they are? My thoughts would be that it isn't possible. Where has this sample come from? Could you ask the author to send you a new copy?

Comment: Where did you get this file from? Looks like something that was somehow deliberately obfuscated

Comment: Where and how did you get the file? How did you open it (= what tool are you using)? You don't give us much to go on and for some that's enough to downvote.

Comment: It is called obfuscation, and is meant to make the code harder or impossible to read. You could try the various online php deobfuscators to see if they can come up with more readable code.

Comment: @Wooble This is not obfuscated.

Comment: if you're using a *nix system, perhaps `$ dos2unix thefile.php` might fix the encoding?

Comment: Could be a variant of this: http://www.virusbtn.com/news/2011/06_09.xml

Comment: @Wooble I just know it's not paid, because licensing has more steps to do in scripts.

Comment: @Wooble Obfuscation does not mean that after it code should not be able to run. And given code is not syntactically correct.

Comment: downvotes happen because people are stupid and expecting something like: `why does my sql query not execute`.. Back to the topic, if the code was obfuscated using zend guard, you need the runtime extension to unobfuscate the code

Comment: @PLB What tells you this code can't run ?

Comment: @Alex-Info.net I don't think it's malicious! it works as expected.

Comment: @revo It is either stolen or malicious. People don't obfuscate code just for fun.

Comment: @hek2mgl It's a raw file, It wasn't encoded and can't guess if it is obfuscated.

Comment: These characters are encryption code to protect against fraud or unauthorized copy (some use this to try to keep the system always working serial key, preventing people manipulate the code). This code is part of a larger class. Which is probably part of a system paid.

Comment: If confidentiality/copyright is not an issue, could you share the raw file with us? I've never see such a thing and I would really enjoy playing with it. Alternatively, please open the file in a hexadecimal editor and post the relevant parts. ([hex plug-in for notepad++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/Hex%20Editor/))

Comment: "I just know it's not paid, because licensing has more steps to do in scripts." Not sure what this means, but it's clearly not open source or you'd have readable source.

Comment: `Windows-1252` or `CP-1252` is a character encoding of the Latin alphabet from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252. This seems to be editor problem rather then PHP problem - just my guess. As RandomSeed said could you share the original file.

One more thing PHP keywords and control structure is as per PHP standards (in english), it is only the names and values are `unreadable`.

Comment: @Wooble I am not referring to the code being paid, but the system should work with serial key, ie if you can manipulate the code, you can use the system without having a valid key
and that I am against.

Comment: going to upload the file.

Comment: @revo Thanks but I could extract what I needed from your post. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears your "spaces" and "dots" are not what they look like. In the code you posted in your question, these are in fact "non-breaking-spaces" (c2 a0) and "ellipsis" (e2 80 a6). These are perfectly valid characters in an identifier.

(thank you StackOverflow for being 100% UTF-8 compatible).

[edit]

... but having looked at the file you linked, the file encoding is rather Windows-1252 (aka. CP1252). The answer is still correct, but the corresponding binary values differ a bit from the ones I mentionned above.

Comment: ... and I *suppose* the actual encoding of your file is UTF-8.

Comment: so the story is that, they are valid characters!

Comment: @revo Yes, but your file is indeed encoded in Windows-1252, as you found out.

Answer (score 3):

Here's it converted to something slightly more readable.

```
public static function    …………  …… …  ( $a , $b )
{
    $c = strpos( some_class::some_function($a), $b );
    return (false !== $c) ? (int)floor($c / 4) : false;
}
```

Without seeing the other function it references or the error message it gives it would be hard to see why it failed.

This code has been deliberately obfuscate for a reason though. Maybe to stop people fiddling or maybe because it's licensed. If it doesn't work maybe you should try contacting the author.